# React app accumulating Base64 encoded images in memory. What could be the cause?

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks

I have a screen in my react App that has a list of items on the left and shows the selected item description on the right panel. Each item has a set of images (usually 3 or 4 images per item). When an item is selected I do a GET request to the back end to load the images of that item. However I'm noticing huge memory increments, it seems like each time an item is selected the images loaded before are not being released from memory:

[image]

I'm was rendering the images as follows:

```
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${image.fileContent}`}/>
```

So, I decided to replace the img tags with a custom component to see if they were being unmounted. So I implemented this component:

```
export class Image extends React.PureComponent<IImageProps, IImageState> {

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.info('Unmounting image: ' + this.props.alt + ', size: ' + (this.props.source.length / 1000) + 'kb');
  }

  render() {
    const { source, alt, title, height, width, className, pinchToZoom } = this.props;

    return pinchToZoom ?
      <PinchZoomPan maxScale={2} position="center">
        <img src={source} alt={alt} title={title} width={width} height={height} className={className}/>
      </PinchZoomPan>
      :
      <img src={source} alt={alt} title={title} width={width} height={height} className={className}/>;
  }
}
```

The component works and I see the logs stating the Image components are being unmounted.

```
Unmounting image: ID_1582, size: 65.67kb
Unmounting image: ID_1584, size: 64.886kb
Unmounting image: ID_1586, size: 66.142kb
Unmounting image: ID_1588, size: 65.462kb
```

However the memory is still increasing and I'm still seeing each new set of images being added to the list in the Chrome DevTools > Application > Images section. The problem seems to go away after I refresh the page and wait a few seconds, the memory drops significantly and goes back to normal.

By the way, the images are loaded as Base64 encoded strings and stored in the component state; each time a new item is selected the state is updated as follows:

```
this.mounted && this.setState({ loadingImages: false, images: response.data });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I already fixed any react warnings I could find and I'm currently not seeing any warnings suggesting I should fix memory leaks here or there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could stop the JS Memory from growing is resetting the state of the component that loads the images to its default state when the user selects a different item from the list.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.state = initialState; // holds the images as a string[]
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<IProductsScreenProps>, 
    prevState: Readonly<IProductsScreenState>, snapshot?: any) {

  // When switching to another item then:
  if (prevProps.selectedItem && this.props.selectedItem &&
  (prevProps.selectedItem.id !== this.props.selectedItem.id)) {

    // Reset this screen to it's initial state:
    this.mounted && this.setState(initialState);

    this.loadItemImages();
  }
}
```

Since I receive the selected item as a prop I use the componentDidUpdate function to check when the selected item changes.

I'm still not able to understand why when I tried to reset the images in the state with an empty array it didn't work.

```
this.mounted && this.setState({ images: [] });
```